# django - why is this not working?

Tags: python, django, media, media-url

i have this image field in my model

```
foto = models.ImageField(upload_to="user/%Y/%m/%d",default='')
```

and in my settings:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, "media")
MEDIA_URL = "/media/"
```

and in my template:

```
<img class="profilfoto" src="{{MEDIA_URL|escapejs}}{{user.foto.name}}" />
```

other images with `upload_to='.'` are being saved right into media folder, but `user` folder isnot being created, why is this?

i ran syncdb and schemamigration, everything works fine but loading this image is giving 404 error as the path isnot there. what can be my mistake?

Comment: Does the server have write access to the media directory?

Comment: Does the user directory exists ? What are its permissions ? Do you get an error or exception at the time you upload the file ?

Comment: @MattWritesCode, i am in local dev.

Comment: @niconoe, no, during upload file, everything is fine - no error message, but once i render it, i dont see image and i debug it, i see 404

Comment: Can you complete your codes in model

Comment: ``Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/". `` what does this mean?

Comment: I have a question, why you use escape here `{{MEDIA_URL|escapejs}}`?

Comment: @catherine, i dont know, i just got tought to do so. :( can you pls explain why i shouldnot do this?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28022/discussion-between-doniyor-and-catherine)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

escapejs

Escapes characters for use in JavaScript strings. This does not make the string safe for use in HTML, but does protect you from syntax errors when using templates to generate JavaScript/JSON.

```
<img class="profilfoto" src="{{MEDIA_URL|escapejs}}{{user.foto.name}}" />
```

Your above code results to, for example: `user/2013\u002D04\u002D10_170411/image.png`, which giving you 404 error while loading this image.

**UPDATE:**

when you save or update an image, you must define the enctype in the form. This will allow you to save an image or a file:

```
<form id="registerform" action="/angemeldet/" method="post" 
    enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
```

AND

```
form = YourForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to add a slash to the begining of your argument in upload_to:

```
foto = models.ImageField(upload_to="/user/%Y/%m/%d",default='')
```

Comment: That will not help, it will reference the root directory

Comment: look at this, maybe it can help : `http://agopian.info/blog/django-filefield-et-imagefield-upload_to-et-shell-python.html`